# Realtime List Of Data in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Good Day, I am currently building a simple CRUD application using Laravel 5.5, and I want My "LIST" to be updated in Realtime whenever the user create a record or update a record . Ive Done some research about  Events and Listeners, Broadcasting, Socket IO, and Vue JS, but still I cant find the right technique to do it . What recommended technology is the best for this Feature? Can somebody Explain to me how to do it ? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Basically my question is "How to do it?" ..

Comment: Broadcasting is the correct answer. [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts) for the client and [Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) to make things easier on you.